# Python - checking whether indexed element of a list exist - Best Practice?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, element

I have something like this:

```
for i in range(0,100,5):

    text = ("Price\t",
            foo[i+0].bar, "\t",
            foo[i+1].bar, "\t",
            foo[i+2].bar, "\t",
            foo[i+3].bar, "\t",
            foo[i+4].bar, "\t",
            "Value", "\n")

    file.writelines(text)
```

My problem is: let's assume that `i=0`. For that case, it is certain that I will have foo[0]. But for indices 1,2,3,4 foo can be empty. For example, if foo is empty for indices greater than 2, I want my text to be like:

```
text = ("Price\t",
        foo[0].bar, "\t",
        foo[1].bar, "\t",
        foo[2].bar, "\n")
```

I thought of using exceptions, but I guess, I will not be able to construct `text` if I do not have all the indexed elements. (Iteration will stop?) So, what is the best practice to do that? I could not think of a short way to do it. Basically what I need is:

```
text= ("Price\t",
        ifexist(foo[0].bar, "\t"),
        ifexist(foo[1].bar, "\t"),
        ifexist(foo[2].bar, "\t"),
        ifexist(foo[3].bar, "\t"),
        ifexist(foo[4].bar, "\t"),
        "Value", "\n")
```

ps: Please do not forget I assumed `i=0` for the sake of simplicity. But in fact, generally I am going to have more than hundred values.

edit: By saying "can be empty", I meant to say that the index might be beyond the size of the list.

edit2: Abot foo:

```
# start class
class Test:
    def __init__(self, bar, bar2, bar3):
        self.bar= a
        self.bar2= b
        self.bar3= c

# end class    


for i in particular_list:
    # read and parse the input file with indeces obtained from particular_list
    # do calculations for temp_bar,temp_bar2,temp_bar3
    foo.append(Test(temp_bar, temp_bar2, temp_bar3))
```

Comment: The minimal fix is to `try` and then catch `except IndexError`. But you are probably better off changing your data structure - why not e.g. a list of tuples instead of a long, flat list?

Comment: What do you mean by `empty`? Do you mean the index is beyond the size of the list? Or that the value of `foo[4]` is `None`? Or that the value of `foo[4]` is `''`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe using a class structure to store the elements seemed like a neat thing to do. but tbh, it's been an intuitive desicion. I tried to use try&except IndexError, but in that case, if one of the elements is missing, I lose the `text`. Could you please show me how to use it?

Comment: @Robᵩ I was trying to say if the index is beyond the size of the list. Thank you, I will edit the question.

Comment: @FrankBrewer Your `Test` class might as well be a tuple since it contains no methods. That would make `foo` a list of tuples that could be easily processed by iterating over the list and `join`-ing the tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be, do not rely on indices but rather structure your code around your data. If you are not indexing, then you would never have issues in IndexError

Consider A List `L` of size `N` to be divided evenly of size `n`. This problem has various  [accepted solutions and approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

The one I generally preach (though you are free to accept any of the alternate approaches) is

```
izip_longest(*[iter(L)]*n)
```

So Given a List

L = [a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub> ... a<sub>N</sub>]

This will generate  ⌊N/n⌋ equally sized chunks. The last shorter lists of size `Mod(N, n)` would be appended by a filler, default in this case is None

L = [[a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub> ... a<sub>n</sub>],[a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub> ... a<sub>n</sub>],[a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub> ... a<sub>n</sub>],.(N Items)..[a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, .. a<sub>N%n</sub>],None,None.. (n terms)]

Now just iterate through this list of lists ignorining any `Nones` in the sublists

**Demo**

```
from itertools import izip_longest
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.bar = n
foo = [Foo(i) for i in range(12)]
for rows in izip_longest(*[iter(foo)]*5):
    print "Price\t{}".format('\t'.join(str(row.bar)
                       for row in rows
                       if row is not None))
```

**Output**

```
Price   0   1   2   3   4
Price   5   6   7   8   9
Price   10  11
```

Answer (score 2):

You would take a different approach; you'd slice the original list, and use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to handle tab-delimiting and newlines:

```
import csv

with open('outputfile', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter='\t')
    for i in range(0, 100, 5):
        row = foo[i:i + 5]
        writer.writerow(['Price'] + row + ['Value'])
```

Slicing on a list always returns a new list object, but if you use slice indices outside the valid range the result is a shorter or empty list:

```
>>> foo = ['spam', 'ham', 'eggs']
>>> foo[0:5]
['spam', 'ham', 'eggs']
>>> foo[5:10]
[]
```

The `csv.writer()` object, meanwhile, takes care of writing the list as a tab-delimited string, plus a newline, to your file.

Instead of using the `csv` module, you would still use slicing, but make use of other techniques that take arbitrary lists of elements. [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) for example:

```
'\t'.join(['Price'] + foo[i:i + 5] + ['Value']) + '\n'
```

would produce one string of tab-delimited values, with a newline appended. This does require that all values in the list passed to `str.join()` are already strings.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what `foo` is. If it is a `list` or `tuple`, there will be no empty indices. If it is a `dict`, referencing an unknown key will result in a `KeyError` exception.

Assuming `foo` is a list of tuples, you can easily print it;

```
In [3]: t = range(30)

In [4]: p = [tuple(t[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(t), 4)]

In [5]: p
Out[5]: [(0, 1, 2), (4, 5, 6), (8, 9, 10), (12, 13, 14), (16, 17, 18), (20, 21, 22), (24, 25, 26), (28, 29)]
```

You can iterate over that list of tuples and print them;

```
In [6]: for k in p:
    print '\t'.join(['Price'] + [str(i) for i in k] + ['Value'])
   ...:     
Price   0   1   2   Value
Price   4   5   6   Value
Price   8   9   10  Value
Price   12  13  14  Value
Price   16  17  18  Value
Price   20  21  22  Value
Price   24  25  26  Value
Price   28  29  Value
```

Comment: added info about `foo`

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment, you could implement something like:

```
def if_exist(seq, index, attr, default):
    """Return seq[index].attr or default."""
    try:
        return getattr(seq[index], attr)
    except IndexError:
        return default
```

Which you could use like:

```
if_exist(foo, 0, "bar", "\t")
```

A demo:

```
>>> if_exist([1, 2, 3], 4, "bar", "\n")
'\n'
```

However, I suspect this to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - if you provide more background information, it is likely that we can help you come up with a different approach that removes this issue entirely.